# Can driver for Windows 10 Desktop be used for Windows 10 IoT directly?

Tags: windowsiot

On a Windows 10 Desktop, I can install Samsung's USB Driver for Mobile Phone, downloadable from [Samsung's Developer portal](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117), so that their mobile phone is recognisable in Windows 10 desktop when connected over USB port.

Since I don't have access to the driver source code, rebuilding the driver to be a Universal Driver is not an option. I'm also not sure whether this is already a universal driver or not.

So, the question is whether it is possible to directly use the driver binaries, such as .sys, .inf file extracted from the desktop driver on the Minnowboard Max running Windows 10 IoT? Would it be compatible? I noticed that in the GPIO sample driver project, in addition to the .sys and .inf file, a ACPI table dat file generated from ASL file is required for deploying the driver, is it possible to get around it if the desktop USB driver can be reusable directly?

Comment: Have you tried using it?

Comment: It depends on which Windows IoT board you are using (i.e. Intel MinnowBoard MAX, RPi2, Dragonboard 410c). If you have desktop x86 compiled driver, then it can possibly run on Windows IoT x86 platform (Intel MinnowBoard MAX). If you have ARM compiled driver, it can possibly run on ARM Windows IoT devices such as RPi2 and Dragonboard 410c. UWP driver can run on any Windows 10 device. But keep in mind that drivers are written for specific hardware so it might be possible that it can run on one but not on different hardware.

Comment: The current Samsung USB driver is surely a x86 compiled driver and I'm going to use the MinnowBoard Max only, since they're of the same processor architecture.

So, are you saying the ASL file is unnecessary here? since the Samsung USB driver surely doesn't include any ACPI file compiled by ASL file.

Comment: @Aron, I haven't tried yet. I'd like to understand whether it's theoretically feasible or not before I purchase the MinnowBoard Max hardware. Do you have any experience in trying out Windows Desktop driver on the MinnowBoard Max?